# Python 3.4.1 - Don't show the final result?

Tags: python, python-3.4

Make a program to find the roots of a quadratic equation using the Bhaskara formule:

for to calculate the square root using the formula: number  ** 0.5

I can put the a,b and c, but when I run the program does't show the result of the roots x1 and x2 ...

This is my code so far:

```
a = int(input("a ")) 
b = int(input("b ")) 
c = int(input("c ")) 
delta = b * b - 4 * a * c 
if (delta >= 0): 
   x1 = (-b + delta ** 0.5) / 2 * a 
   x2 = (-b - (delta) ** 0.5) / 2 * a 
   print("x1: ", x1) 
   print("x2: ", x2)
```

Comment: If it's not printing anything, then it kind of hints your `if delta >= 0` isn't true...

Comment: So ... I need to change (delta > 0) and to put another print below the last print ... right?

Comment: @Susan: That depends. What do you want to do if `delta < 0`? For example, if you enter `3`, `4`, and `5`, do you want to print two complex roots (in which case, just remove the `if` check entirely), or no roots (in which case, your code is working), or an error (in which case, add an `else:` so you can `print('No real roots because delta is negative:", delta)` or similar).

Comment: Also, for future reference, a question should show the actual input, expected/desired output, and actual output, not just a statement that the output is wrong.

Comment: Huum ... so I only need take off the (if) ?? Beacause if I take off  will stay ... delta > 0 ... and below, will stay the same ... ?!

Comment: @Susan: No, if you want complex roots, remove the entire `if delta >=0:` line, and dedent the next four lines, so there's no check at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `a`, `b`, and `c` real values have two roots (except in the case where the delta is 0)—but sometimes the roots are complex numbers, not real numbers.

In particular, if I remember correctly:

- If `delta > 0`, there are two real roots.
- If `delta == 0`, there is only one root, the real number `-b/(2*a)`.
- If `delta < 0`, there are two complex roots (which are always conjugates).

If you do your math with complex numbers, you can use the same formula, `(-b +/- delta**0.5) / 2a`, for all three cases, and you'll get two real numbers, or `0` twice, or two complex numbers, as appropriate.

There are also ways to calculate the real and imaginary parts of the third case without doing complex math, but since Python makes complex math easy, why bother unless you're specifically trying to learn about those ways?

---

So, if you always want to print 2 roots, all you have to do is remove that `if delta >= 0:` line (and dedent the next few lines). Raising a negative float to the `0.5` power will give you a complex automatically, and that will make the rest of the expression complex. Like this:

```
delta = b * b - 4 * a * c 
x1 = (-b + delta ** 0.5) / 2 * a 
x2 = (-b - (delta) ** 0.5) / 2 * a 
print("x1: ", x1) 
print("x2: ", x2)
```

---

If you only want 0-2 real roots, your code is already correct as-is. You might want to add a check for `delta == 0`, or just for `x1 == x2`, so you don't print the same value twice. Like this:

```
delta = b * b - 4 * a * c 
if delta >= 0:
    x1 = (-b + delta ** 0.5) / 2 * a 
    x2 = (-b - (delta) ** 0.5) / 2 * a 
    print("x1: ", x1)
    if x1 != x2:
        print("x2: ", x2)
```

---

If you want some kind of error message, all you need to do is add an `else` clause. Something like this:

```
delta = b * b - 4 * a * c 
if delta >= 0:
    x1 = (-b + delta ** 0.5) / 2 * a 
    x2 = (-b - (delta) ** 0.5) / 2 * a 
    print("x1: ", x1)
    print("x2: ", x2)
else:
    print('No real solutions because of negative delta: ", delta)
```

---

Which one do you want? I have no idea. That's a question for you to answer. Once you decide what output you want for, say, `3`, `4`, and `5`, you can pick the version that gives you that output.

Comment: A minor correction, If delta == 0, -b/(2*a) is the only root. But I'm sure you know that. :)

Comment: @PM2Ring: Thanks, my brain may know that but obviously my fingers don't; I'll fix it.

Comment: @abarnert -hi,(sorry for being slow,my internet is terrible this week)thank's, know I understood XD I get confused with the = and ==, sorry T.T